# php.ini configuration items under centos

Tags: php, ubuntu, centos

Configuration File Path : **/etc/php.ini**

Additional .ini files under **/etc/php.d** : curl.ini, fileinfo.ini,gd.ini,json.ini, mysql.ini, mysqli.ini, pdo.ini, pdo_mysql.ini, pdo_sqlite.ini, phar.ini,sqlite3.ini,zip.ini

The problem is I can not find where to config these items like "post_max_size", "disable_functions" under .ini files, **should I add them into php.ini myself ?**

PS: under windows or ubuntu these configuration items seems in the php.ini, am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can  do from php functon ini_set

please have look on this

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php

Answer (score 1):

You should put configurations of the core into the php.ini file and configurations of extensions in the php.d folder.

Comment: that is to say, I should add them into the php.ini file myself?

Comment: can i comment on this answer again?